# Hibernate lazy-load application design

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, lazy-loading, application-design

I tend to use [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/docs) in combination with [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) framework and it's declarative transaction demarcation capabilities (e.g., [@Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)).

As we all known, hibernate tries to be as *non-invasive* and as *transparent* as possible, however this proves **a bit more challenging** when employing **`lazy-loaded`** relationships.

---

I see a number of design alternatives with different levels of transparency.

1. Make relationships not lazy-loaded (e.g., `fetchType=FetchType.EAGER)`

   - This vioalites the entire idea of lazy loading ..
2. Initialize collections using `Hibernate.initialize(proxyObj);`

   - This implies relatively high-coupling to the DAO
   - Although we can define an interface with `initialize`, other implementations are not guaranteed to provide any equivalent.
3. Add transaction behaviour to the persistent `Model` objects themselves (using either [dynamic proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) or `@Transactional`)

   - I've not tried the dynamic proxy approach, although I never seemed to get @Transactional working on the persistent objects themselves. Probably due to that hibernate is operation on a proxy to bein with.
   - Loss of control when transactions are actually taking place
4. Provide both lazy/non-lazy API, e.g, `loadData()` and `loadDataWithDeps()`

   - Forces the application to know when to employ which routine, again tight coupling
   - Method overflow, `loadDataWithA()`, ...., `loadDataWithX()`
5. Force lookup for dependencies, e.g., by only providing `byId()` operations

   - Requires alot of non-object oriented routines, e.g., `findZzzById(zid)`, and then `getYyyIds(zid)` instead of `z.getY()`
   - It can be useful to fetch each object in a collection one-by-one if there's a large processing overhead between the transactions.
6. Make part of the *application* @Transactional instead of only the [DAO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

   - Possible considerations of nested transactions
   - Requires routines adapted for transaction management (e.g., suffiently small)
   - Small programmatic impact, although might result in large transactions
7. Provide the DAO with dynamic [fetch profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3524), e.g., `loadData(id, fetchProfile);`

   - Applications must know which profile to use when
8. AoP type of transactions, e.g., intercept operations and perform transactions when necessary

   - Requires byte-code manipulation or proxy usage
   - Loss of control when transactions are performed
   - Black magic, as always :)

Did I miss any option?

---

Which is your preferred approach when trying to minimize the impact of `lazy-loaded` relationships in your application design?

(Oh, and sorry for [WoT](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wall%20of%20text))

Comment: example for option 2 & 5: http://m-hewedy.blogspot.ch/2010/03/hibernate-failed-to-lazily-initialize.html

Comment: Could you please provide an example for option 4?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> As we all known, hibernate tries to be as non-invasive and as transparent as possible

I would say the initial assumption is wrong. Transaparent persistence is a myth, since application always should take care of entity lifecycle and of size of object graph being loaded.

Note that Hibernate can't read thoughts, therefore if you know that you need a particular set of dependencies for a particular operation, you need to express your intentions to Hibernate somehow.

From this point of view, solutions that express these intentions explicitly (namely, 2, 4 and 7) look reasonable and don't suffer from the lack of transparency.

Comment: You're right of course, the *as transparent as possible* only works so far. Those are some nice choices you went for.

Comment: IMHO: perfectly correct answer. Indeed, it is a myth.  BTW: my vote would be for options 4 and 7 (or move away from the ORM at all)

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure which problem (caused by lazyness) you're hinting to, but for me the biggest pain is to avoid losing session context in my own application caches. Typical case:

- object `foo` is loaded and put into a map;
- another thread takes this object from the map and calls `foo.getBar()` (something that was never called before and is lazy evaluated);
- boom!

So, to address this we have a number of rules:

- wrap sessions as transparently as possible (e.g. `OpenSessionInViewFilter` for webapps);
- have common API for threads/thread pools where db session bind/unbind is done somewhere high in the hierarchy (wrapped in `try/finally`) so subclasses don't have to think about it;
- when passing objects between threads, pass IDs instead of objects themselves. Receiving thread can load object if it needs to;
- when caching objects, never cache objects but their ids. Have an abstract method in your DAO or manager class to load the object from 2nd level Hibernate cache when you know the ID. The cost of retrieving objects from 2nd level Hibernate cache is still far cheaper than going to DB.

This, as you can see, is indeed nowhere close to *non-invasive and transparent*. But the cost is still bearable, to compare with the price I'd have to pay for eager loading. The problem with latter is that sometimes it leads to the butterfly effect when loading single referenced object, let alone a collection of entities. Memory consumption, CPU usage and latency to mention the least are also far worse, so I guess I can live with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The loss of `transparency` is from forcing the application to care about loading lazy objects. If everything was fetched eagerly the application *could* be completely unaware of whether the objects are persisted into a database or not, since `Foo.getBar()` will always succeed. > `when passing objects between threads, pass IDs`, yes, this would correspond to #5.

Answer (score 3):

A very common pattern is to use [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) if you're building a web application.

If you're building a service, I would open the TX on the public method of the service, rather than on the DAOs, as very often a method requires to get or update several entities.

This will solve any "Lazy Load exception". If you need something more advanced for performance tuning, I think fetch profiles is the way to go.

Comment: I guess you wanted to say: [A very common antipattern ...](http://java.dzone.com/articles/opensessioninview-antipattern). Although I would agree with opening TX on the service level, but usage of the `OSIV` is still an antipattern and leads to very serious problems like inability to deal gracefully with exceptions or performance degradation. To sum up: **IMHO** OSIV is an easygoing solution, but good only for a toy-projects.