# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have two classes like this:

```
public class Indicator implements Serializable {
...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "indicator",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<IndicatorAlternateLabel>  indicatorAlternateLabels;

    public List<IndicatorAlternateLabel> getIndicatorAlternateLabels() {
        return indicatorAlternateLabels;
    }

        public void setIndicatorAlternateLabels(List<IndicatorAlternateLabel> indicatorAlternateLabels) {
            this.indicatorAlternateLabels = indicatorAlternateLabels;
        }
...
    }

public class IndicatorAlternateLabel implements Serializable {
...
 @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IndicatorID")
    @XmlTransient
    private Indicator indicator;
...
}
```

When I use them like this:

```
 public MetricTypeDetail getMetricTypeDetail(Integer metricTypeId) {
        Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Indicator.class, "sub")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("number", metricTypeId))
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).setCacheable(true);
        crit.setMaxResults(1);
        Indicator indicator=(Indicator) crit.uniqueResult();
        MetricTypeDetail metricTypeDetail=new MetricTypeDetail(indicator);
        List<IndicatorAlternateLabel> indicatorAlternateLabels = null;
        indicatorAlternateLabels=indicator.getIndicatorAlternateLabels();
        metricTypeDetail.setIndicatorAlternateLabels(indicatorAlternateLabels);
        return metricTypeDetail;
    }
```

This code returns an exception:
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.porism.service.domain.Indicator.indicatorAlternateLabels, no session or session was closed

Any idea? I'm very new to Hibernate

Answer (score 78):

Lazy exceptions occur when you fetch an object typically containing a collection which is lazily loaded, and try to access that collection.

You can avoid this problem by

- accessing the lazy collection within a transaction.
- Initalizing the collection using `Hibernate.initialize(obj);`
- Fetch the collection in another transaction
- Use [`Fetch profiles`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e3524) to select lazy/non-lazy fetching runtime
- Set fetch to non-lazy (which is generally not recommended)

Further I would recommend looking at the **`related`** links to your right where this question has been answered many times before. Also see [Hibernate lazy-load application design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027013/hibernate-lazy-load-application-design).

Comment: Fetching means querying with JPQL I think cause  just using transaction to retrieve association through collection doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that you're not fetching the Joined Set.  Be sure to include the set in your HQL:

```
public List<Node> getAll() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Node as n LEFT JOIN FETCH n.nodeValues LEFT JOIN FETCH n.nodeStats");
    return  query.list();
}
```

Where your class has 2 sets like:

```
public class Node implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<NodeValue> nodeValues;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<NodeStat> nodeStats;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  swich fetchType from **LAZY** to **EAGER**

```
...
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<NodeValue> nodeValues;
...
```

But in this case your app will fetch data from DB anyway.
If this query very hard - this may impact on performance.
More here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html

==> 73

Answer (score 1):

as suggested [here](https://www.xspdf.com/help/50485645.html) solving the famous LazyInitializationException is one of the following methods:

**(1) Use Hibernate.initialize**

Hibernate.initialize(topics.getComments());

**(2) Use JOIN FETCH**

You can use the JOIN FETCH syntax in your JPQL to explicitly fetch the child collection out. This is somehow like EAGER fetching.

**(3) Use OpenSessionInViewFilter**

LazyInitializationException often occurs in the view layer. If you use Spring framework, you can use OpenSessionInViewFilter. However, I do not suggest you to do so. It may leads to a performance issue if not used correctly.