# Get data in a many-to-many connection

Tags: java, database, hibernate, many-to-many

I got a problem, with my hibernate database connection. At first I post some data:

Objects.java:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "objects", schema="genmeta")
public class Objects {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int o_id;
    private String o_name;
    private String o_desc;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "genmeta.object_tg_assc", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "o_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tg_id") })
    private Set<TemplateGroup> templateGroups;
    @Transient
    private boolean templateGroupsLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Getters and Setters 
     */
}
```

TemplateGroup.java:

```
public class TemplateGroup {
    @Id
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int tg_id;
    private String tg_name;
    private String tg_desc;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "templateGroups")
    private Set<Objects> objects;

    /**
     * Getters and Setters 
     */
}
```

My Problem is, how I could get from my class Object later the data?

Here is my first try:
Code Example:

```
public Set<TemplateGroup> loadTemplateGroups(Objects myObjects) {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Set<TemplateGroup> myTG = myObjects.getTemplateGroups();
    session.close();
    return myTG;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Best regards
Björn

Comment: You do not need to explicitly retrieve the TemplateGroup list. When you access the `templateGroups` set from the `Objects` instance, hibernate will fire a query based on the mapping and populate the list with the right data. Are you getting an empty set?

Comment: Yes. Because of this Set I thought, that I have to load the data like this way. Did you know another way for me?

Comment: You will have to enable hibernate sql logging and check the SQL generated and logged by hibernate when you access `templateGroups`.

Comment: Do you have an example for me? Didn't know what you mean. Everybody said: "When you acces templateGroups". How?

Comment: If you do a simple `object.getTemplateGroups()`, hibernate will fire a query to get the contents of the set. In hibernate configuration file, you can enable sql logging. e.g., `<property name="show_sql">true</property>`. Check this link for further details, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql.

Comment: Ok, I changed my example. Now I got this error: `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: db.hibernate.classes.Objects.templateGroups, could not initialize proxy - no Session`. I found this Posting [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404599/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role). What did he mean with "accessing the lazy collection within a transaction"

Comment: This error is thrown because you are retrieve the `Objects` instance in one transaction and calling `getTemplateGroups()` in another.

Comment: But I didn't know at the time, where I want to load my object, that I want to load the templateGroup, too. I want only load it, if I need it.

Comment: This cannot be achieve in different transactions. Both should happen in the same transaction. If you want to load the template groups in another transaction, you will have to retrieve the `Objects` again from the database.

Comment: Or try Session.refresh(object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: db.hibernate.classes.Objects.templateGroups, could not initialize proxy - no Session` exception is thrown because you are retrieving the `Objects` instance in one transaction and calling `getTemplateGroups()` in another(or after the first transaction is committed). You should not open another session to get the template groups.

You need to do something like below:

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
Objects object = <Code to retrieve the Objects instance>
Set<TemplateGroup> templateGroups = object.getTemplateGroups();
templateGroups.size(); // as an example
session.close();
```