# Error serializing Hibernate entity object list to JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, serialization, jackson

I have fetched a list of objects of type `Company` from the database. But when trying to serialize the list using Jackson to JSON, throws an error

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.zerosolutions.repository.entity.CompanySector.companies, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.zerosolutions.repository.entity.Company["sector"]->com.zerosolutions.repository.entity.CompanySector["companies"])
```

Company:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "sector")
private CompanySector sector;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private CompanyProfile profile;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private CompanyAddress address;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Job> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public CompanySector getSector() {
    return sector;
}

public void setSector(CompanySector sector) {
    this.sector = sector;
}

public CompanyProfile getProfile() {
    return profile;
}

public void setProfile(CompanyProfile profile) {
    this.profile = profile;
}

public CompanyAddress getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(CompanyAddress address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public List<Job> getJobs() {
    return jobs;
}

public void setJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
    this.jobs = jobs;
}   

}
```

CompanySector:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sectors")
public class CompanySector {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="sector")
private String sector;


@OneToMany(mappedBy="sector", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSector() {
    return sector;
}

public void setSector(String sector) {
    this.sector = sector;
}

public List<Company> getCompanies() {
    return companies;
}

}
```

Conversion code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCompanyList", method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces={ "application/json"})
public @ResponseBody String getCompanyList() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<Company> companyList = companyServices.getCompanyList();
        String companyListString = mapper.writeValueAsString(companyList); // this line throws error        
        return companyListString;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions what might be wrong here ?

Fetching list:

```
public List<Company> getCompanyList(){

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<Company> companies = session.createCriteria(Company.class).list();
        logger.debug(companies);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("companies fetched");
        return companies;
    } catch(Exception e){
        logger.error("Exceptino thrown: " + e);
        tx.rollback();
        return null;
    } finally{
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you'll want to see all `Companies` every time you retrieve a `CompanySector` then change your field mapping for `Companies` to:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="sector", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Another approach use **Hibernate.initialize** :

```
Hibernate.initialize(companySector.getCompany());
```

Also see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027013/hibernate-lazy-load-application-design) it's very helpful

Comment: that I know . But here I am fetching list of `Company` objects not CompanySector

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I tried changing fetch strategy in `Company` for `CompanySector` to `LAZY` but I get the same error. Hoping it would create a proxy for `CompanySector`.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary aren;t you fetching company objects from companysector ?? if no ,what is the class you are fetching company objects from ?!

Comment: I am fetching the list directly without using CompanySector. I have added fetch code to the end of my post. take a look.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary do you have `<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>  ` in your configuration ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574236/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-sess) link